# Get all Github issues from repo with specific label?

Tags: api, github

From the Github web interface can I click on a label, and it will list all issues that have that label. This is what I want, but just from a script.

When I look at the [API](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/) I can't see anything that would give me just that.

Can it be done without querying every single issue in a repo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Getting all the issues from Travis that have the label 'bug':

```
curl 'https://api.github.com/repos/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues?labels=bug'
```

See https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#parameters